# AutoPostBack using TwitterBootstrap layout - MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, cascadingdropdown

I'm not sure what I'm missing when I select an Item from DropdownList (Campus) I want the AutoPostBack  fire and load the another DropdownList which is Building but its not happening.... I'm trying to work with autopostback on a DropDownListFor

**What is the problem:** the below code works fine for any regular MVC 4 layout but having problem only with
the `TwitterBootStrap` layout, what do i need to change or do to work with TwitterBootStrap layout?

here is my code:,

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CampusSelect", "Facility", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Campus_Building" }))
{ 
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
            m =>  m.CampusId,
            new SelectList(Model.GetAllCampus(), "CampusId", "Text"),
           string.Empty
        )
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#CampusId').change(function () {
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is how I do it in same scenario: Remove your script and add `, new { onchange = "$(this.form).submit();"})` to your `DropDownListFor` after the `string.Empty`. But as a caveat, using your code also worked for me.

Comment: `using your code also worked for me` are you using twitter bootstrap layout?

Comment: yes... Are you sure the `ID` of the dropdownlist is correct? Did the code I provide work for you?

Comment: yes the ID of the dropdownlist is correct, however when i tried your first suggestion it does work... what might be wrong using script?

Comment: Can you be more specific in what the problem is? Are you getting script errors?

Comment: sorry, I'm not getting any script error its silently failed meaning when i change the dropdownlist value it suppose to fire an event on the controller which is not happening with the script but where as after your first suggestion i modified my code and it does fire change event and i able to catch in the controller and i do have  [httpost] on the controller.

Comment: I went ahead and posted my answer since it worked for you. Your code worked for me both in bootstrap and in other templates. The only time it **didn't work**, and silently failed like you described, is when there was another element of ID "CampusId" on that page. Can you verify you don't have another element with that ID?

Comment: I'm looking into it and very curious to know what is going on and i will post you my update.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, you can use the following code the apply your `onchange` event.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m =>  m.CampusId,
    new SelectList(Model.GetAllCampus(), "CampusId", "Text"),
    string.Empty,
    new { onchange = "$(this.form).submit();"}
)
```

However, your script should also work as is... it is just more cumbersome. I assume it isn't working because there is another element with `id="CampusId"` on the page somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong overload. You are not setting the id of the drop down. It should be:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m =>  m.CampusId,
    new SelectList(Model.GetAllCampus(), "CampusId", "Text"),
    new { id = "CampusId" }
)
```

Then your script will work.

In order to avoid confusion with overloads, use [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/):

```
@Html.Bootstrap().DropDownListFor(m =>  m.CampusId, new SelectList(Model.GetAllCampus(), "CampusId", "Text")).Id("CampusId")
```

Comment: His dropdownlist ID was already likely "CampusId", I don't think that alone will fix it (and it is missing a `@` `new { @id =`) I haven't seen that TwitterBootstrapMVC before tho... I'll need to check it out.